# Play streaming video on mac

Tags: macos, stream, udp, streaming, video-streaming

I need to play a video coming from a stream of bytes arriving live via UDP on Mac, I have seen AVPlayer but it only seems to be possible to get the data from a given URL, how could I do this?

Thank you